# ¿Existe o debería crearse un grupo en Telegram de Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

Tal como formulo en el título, creo que sería interesante la existencia de un grupo en Telegram de Stack Overflow. Puede que ya exista y no he dado con él, pero sin duda a mucha gente le interesaría.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, no veo porqué tendría que haber tal grupo. Creo que la interfaz de [se] ofrece más potencia que Telegram para nuestros menesteres.

Comment: Además, como propuesta la verdad que tiene patas cortas... ¿En qué te estás basando? ¿Cuál sería la ventaja? ¿Qué datos sustentan tu propuesta? ¿Qué ejemplos de otras comunidades podrías aportar y en qué se beneficiaron?

Comment: Pedro, hay un [chat general oficial](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) (al que se puede participar con 20 de reputación) y muchos otros sobre distintas tecnologias o temas. No es necesario de herramientas externas. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenido Pedro.

Usalmente el contenido de esta publicación se incluye en un comentario pero me ha salido bastante largo.

Veo que tienes 1 de reputación, que no has realizado el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (tour) y que esta es tu primer pregunta. Esta ha sido migrada a Meta que es el espacio donde se tratan temas sobre el funcionamiento de https://es.stackoverflow.com incluyendo la realización de preguntas como la que has hecho. En Meta los  votos tienen un sentido distinto al sitio principal y tanto en el sitio principal como en Meta los votos tienen un sentido muy distinto a "like" o +1 de otros sitios tales como Facebook, Google+, entre otros.

Lo que se ofrece y espera de los usuarios nuevos es que accedan a y publiquen preguntas y respuestas acerca de los temas que se indican en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Las publicaciones referidas, si son apreciadas por la comunidad te darán puntos de reputación y eventualmente privilegios. Uno de esos privilegios es el publicar directamente en Meta.

Como te darás cuenta, esta sitio ni es una red social típica ni es un foro típico. Tiene funciones que coinciden pero su forma de operar y la comunidad que participa, en mi opinión, son únicos.

Si lo que estás buscando es acceder al sitio en un dispositivo móvil, has click en el enlace "móvil" al pide de esta página.

> P.D. No uso Telegram, no sé cómo se podría saber si existe un grupo en dicho servicio. Participo desde que se puso "la primera piedra" y esta es la primera pregunta que veo que hable sobre Telegram, así que dudo mucho que a los miembros de esta comunidad les interese una aplicación como esa para los fines de este sitio.
>
> Al momento [telegram](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telegram) sólo tiene dos preguntas, esta que fue migrada y otra más.

Comment: Porque la respuesta de Ruben tiene votos negativos

Comment: Sí, por no responder a la pregunta. Incluso con la PD creo que decir que "*no hay preguntas de Telegram*" no atiende a si debería crearse o no (nada personal, debo tener 170 +1s en publicaciones tuyas). PD: pensá en Telegram como si fuese un WhatsApp con anfetaminas.

Comment: La parte de "dudo mucho..." la atiende. Aquí si se valen las opiniones :)

Comment: Por cierto, de ninguna forma tomo los votos negativos como algo personal ni espero que todas mis publicaciones en Meta tengan votos positivos